# Explain this proof about Directional Derivative

Tags: calculus

I am interested in a better explanation about the proof of $\nabla_{\mathbf{v}}{f}(\mathbf{x}) = \nabla f(\mathbf{x}) \cdot \mathbf{v}$ [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directional_derivative).

I don't understand the following expression:

$0=\lim_{t\rightarrow 0}\frac {f(x+tv)-f(x)-t*D_f(x)(v)} t =\lim_{t\rightarrow 0}\frac {f(x+tv)-f(x)} t - D_f(x)(v)=\nabla_v f(x)-D_f(x)(v) ...$

My questions are:

1. Where does the limit $0=\lim_{t\rightarrow 0}\frac {f(x+tv)-f(x)-t*D_f(x)(v)} t$ come from?
2. What is the asterisk  $*$ in the above expression?

Answer (score 0):

1. It comes from the definition of derivative of $f$ at a point $x_0$: it is a linear map $L\colon\mathbb R^n\longrightarrow\mathbb R$ such that$$\lim_{x\to _0}\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)-L(x-x_0)}{\lVert x-x_0\rVert}=0.$$
2. It stands for multiplication (remember that $L$ is linear).

Comment: I don't understand $\lim_{x\to _0}\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)-L(x-x_0)}{\lVert x-x_0\rVert}=0$. I think there is a factor missing in this formula. Is this correct?: $\lim_{x\to _0}\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)-{\lVert x-x_0\rVert}L(x-x_0)}{\lVert x-x_0\rVert}=0$ (read the article [Fréchet derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_derivative))

Comment: No. It is *exactly* as I wrote it.